# plot matrices in desired colors

Tags: matlab, video, colors, matrix

how is it possible to assign certain color to a value from matrix.
For example I have a 10by10 matrix with values from 0 to 9.
Afterwards I'd like to get a "chess board" where 0 = white, 1 = black, 2 = blue...etc...

2nd question
if I run some operations where my matrices change with each loop and I run let's say 10 lops (k = 10) - is it possible to make a video out of this 10 plot pictures I'll be getting after each loop. (I'm programming some kind of cellular automaton, so I'd like to see how the situation changes over time).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
%# lets create a 10-by-10 matrix, of values in the range [0,9]
M = fspecial('gaussian',10,2.5);
M = (M-min(M(:))) ./ range(M(:));
M = round(M*9);

%# prepare video output
vid = VideoWriter('vid.avi');
vidObj.Quality = 100;
vid.FrameRate = 5;
open(vid);

%# display matrix
h = imagesc(M);
axis square
caxis([0 10])
colormap(jet(10))
colorbar

%# capture frame
writeVideo(vid,getframe);

%# iterate changing matrix
for i=1:50
    M = rem(M+1,10);          %# circular increment
    set(h, 'CData',M)         %# update displayed matrix

    writeVideo(vid,getframe); %# capture frame

    drawnow                   %# force redisplay
end

%# close and save video output
close(vid);
```

[image]

You can use a custom colormap, simply create a matrix `cmap` of size 10-by-3, each row contains the RGB values, and pass it to the call `colormap(cmap)`

---

For MATLAB versions older than R2010b, you can use the [avifile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/avifile.html) function, instead of VideoWriter:

```
%# prepare video output
vid = avifile('vid.avi', 'fps',5, 'quality',100);

%# iterations
for i=1:50
    %# ...

    %# capture frame
    vid = addframe(vid, getframe(gcf));

    drawnow
end

%# close and save video output
vid = close(vid);
```

Comment: Thanks, I just don't understand why you did this: M = (M-min(M(:))) ./ range(M(:)); when range(M(:)) is 1 and M-min(M(:)) divided with 1 is the same number?

Comment: How come that when I write: vid = VideoWriter('vid.avi'); matlab returns: ??? Undefined function or method 'VideoWriter' for input arguments of type 'char'?

Comment: @kojikurac: The first three lines were just so that I create a sample matrix like the one you described (contains natural numbers from 0 to 9). This should be replaced with the actual data you have. For the other part, VideoWriter was introduced in MATLAB R2010b. In case you have an older version, you can use the older `avifile` function. I update the answer to show how to use this function.